# Is there way to use global symbols from other binary without linking it in

Tags: assembly, ld, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to convert a game for Soviet PDP11 compatible machine. Since it has strict memory limitation - 56K of RAM,  I have to load some part of code during runtime.
Which means that I need to build several binary modules which cross-reference symbols from each other.
I'm using GAS and LD.

Is there a way to accomplish this simply using these tools?

For example, one binary module file wants to load another binary module, to do that it has to know the size of the other binary.
The size is available as a symbol like this:

```
.title OtherModule

begin:
  some code
end:

.equiv SizeOfTheOtherModuleInWords, ((end - begin) / 2)
```

Another example, each level in the game loads separately and contains code which calls subroutines from the main engine which always resides in memory.

---

I found a solution via linker script. I can use `/DISCARD/` section to exclude files from linking.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
OUTPUT_ARCH(pdp11)

INPUT(core.o bootstrap.o)
OUTPUT(AKU.SAV)

FileSizeCoreWords = ((FileEndCore - FileBeginCore) / 2);

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0;
.text :
    {
        bootstrap.o (.text)
    }
.data :
    {
        bootstrap.o (.data)
    }
.bss :
    {
        bootstrap.o (.bss)
    }
/DISCARD/ :
    {
        core.o
    }
}
```

Comment: You could check out the toolchain shipped with 2.11BSD.  It contains a linker that can generate overlays from object files, managing this swapping automatically.

Comment: The code will run without an operating system in memory. Anyway, the machine uses RT-11 operating system and binaries format generated by Ld isn't compatible with the RT-11. I have to convert them in order to make them loadable by the RT-11.

Comment: That's given.  The same is needed when making binaries with the GNU toolchain.  I'm not sure how the overlay code works, but I imagine it can be used or adapted for a machine without an operating system.

Comment: Overlays, sounds complicated. I simply looking for an easy way to include symbols from another module. Is there any other way besides overlays?

Comment: The thing you want to build is overlays.  What I'm trying to tell you is that you can avoid the need to build your own overlays by using an existing implementation.

Comment: You are using LD, do you have any experience writing linker scripts?

Comment: I had no idea about the linker script.

Comment: I'm not sure how the linker script can help me. I don't want to link object files together into a single binary. I need them separate, but one binary needs to reference symbols from another binary.

Comment: @OlegTsymbalyuk That's the whole point of overlays (which you can make with linker scripts): these split the program into multiple overlays of which only one is loaded into memory at a time.  Typically, all the overlays are bundled into one file on disk, but it is also possible to have each overlay in its own file.  As far as I know, the GNU linker has no way to do exactly what you want, but as I said, you can reach your ultimate goal much easier with overlays.

Comment: After some, reading I agree that overlays are a great way to accomplish the task.

Comment: But how to split overlays into multiple files? Probably I can use overlays in a single file, but at least it will require to align each overlay by 512bytes(disk sector or block) and I will need to know starting sectors of each overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU ld has the option `--just-symbols` which takes an already linked file to load the symbols from.

Comment: This option works with object file generated by GNU `as` as well :) There is a chance that I will try to use overlays later, but your answer is what I really searched for. Thanks!